# rails heroku deployment error: precompile assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

My rails application works fine in localhost, but failed to be deployed on heroku. I've searched/tried for reasons related to precompilation of assets (e.g.: heroku run rake assets:precompile), but apparently those methods don't seem to give any positive results.

Here is the heroku logs

```
``2013-01-13T23:21:36+00:00 app[web.1]:         Called from: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
2013-01-13T23:21:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-01-13T23:21:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-01-13T23:21:37+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-13 23:21:37] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-01-13T23:21:37+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-13 23:21:37] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=17458
2013-01-13T23:21:37+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-13 23:21:37] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-01-13T23:21:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-01-13T23:21:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:17458
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 81.83.230.107 at 2013-01-13 23:21:39 +0000
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html within layouts/application (29.9ms)
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 73ms
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap-responsive", :media => "all" %>
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=safe-plateau-7008.herokuapp.com fwd=81.83.230.107 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=869ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap-responsive.css isn't precompiled):
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     9: 
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>Leanbrewsite</title>
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3282064974730572949_33935860'
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:21:39+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2013-01-13T23:26:47+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-01-13T23:27:04+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v13 created by didier@leanbrew.com
2013-01-13T23:27:04+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 197fc85 by didier@leanbrew.com
2013-01-13T23:27:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-01-13T23:27:05+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-01-13T23:27:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-01-13T23:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-13 23:27:08] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-01-13T23:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-01-13T23:27:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 56864`
2013-01-13T23:27:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-01-13T23:27:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-01-13T23:27:18+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-01-13T23:27:18+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-01-13T23:27:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-01-13T23:27:23+00:00 app[web.1]:         SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
2013-01-13T23:27:23+00:00 app[web.1]:         This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
2013-01-13T23:27:23+00:00 app[web.1]:         provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
2013-01-13T23:27:23+00:00 app[web.1]:         cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
2013-01-13T23:27:23+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:27:23+00:00 app[web.1]:         future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.
2013-01-13T23:27:23+00:00 app[web.1]:         Called from: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
2013-01-13T23:27:23+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:27:25+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-13 23:27:25] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-01-13T23:27:25+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-13 23:27:25] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-01-13T23:27:25+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-13 23:27:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=56864
2013-01-13T23:27:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-01-13T23:27:29+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-01-13T23:27:29+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:56864
2013-01-13T23:27:29+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-01-13T23:27:29+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-01-13T23:27:29+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:27:29+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:27:29+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 81.83.230.107 at 2013-01-13 23:27:29 +0000
2013-01-13T23:27:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-01-13T23:27:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html within layouts/application (246.2ms)
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 948ms
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap-responsive.css isn't precompiled):
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>Leanbrewsite</title>
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     9: 
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap-responsive", :media => "all" %>
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2492136347222149984_29076580'
2013-01-13T23:27:36+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=safe-plateau-7008.herokuapp.com fwd=81.83.230.107 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=8ms connect=23ms service=7130ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 81.83.230.107 at 2013-01-13 23:38:35 +0000
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html within layouts/application (0.3ms)
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap-responsive.css isn't precompiled):
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>Leanbrewsite</title>
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     9: 
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2492136347222149984_29076580'
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-13T23:38:36+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=safe-plateau-7008.herokuapp.com fwd=81.83.230.107 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=9ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap-responsive", :media => "all" %>
2013-01-13T23:38:35+00:00 app[web.1]:
``
```

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information on what you've tried so far?

Comment: What I tried:

(1) ``heroku run rake assets:precompile``
(2) added the following to my application.css file: 

``/* ...
*= require bootstrap 
*= require bootstrap-responsive 
*= require_tree .
*= require_self

# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
       
*/

 @import "bootstrap.css";
 @import "bootstrap-responsive.css";
``

(3) add the following to my application.js file: 

``//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
``
(4) Added following to config/environments/production.rb:
 
``  config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css)``

Answer (score 0):

Rails by default, only creates one application.js and one application.css. If you want multiple destination files, not sure how you do it!

It looks like you have things setup to produce just one the application.js and the one application.css file. So all of bootstrap will be in your application.css, meaning I don't think you need to include the bootstrap css separately. Try just removing the boostrap css tag and see what happens.

If that doesn't work, I'd look in public/assets. Rails is happy with your application.js and application.css, I suspect that's because they exist in public/assets and bootstrap-responsive.css doesn't. So that's where I would start debugging from.